# Select Inner component in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to do a Main component (in the example, Container), which can hold a inner component selectable, in the example is harcoded (the condition is set to true).

I need the inner component extends from React.Component, i cant use it like a function: `const ChildOne = (.... )`

There're 2 child component, the idea is to use more of them.

But, i can't, i got error when rendering the inner component:

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
>   return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you
>   meant to call this function rather than return it.

```
class ChildOne extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p> Child One </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Child Two</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let condition = true;   //Just for testing purpose

        let comp = null;
        if (condition)
            comp = ChildOne;
        else
            comp = ChildTwo;

        return (
                <main>
                    {comp}          
                </main>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div><Container /></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01L8amgs/

I ran out of ideas... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use capitalized letter, to assign a React custom component to a variable. Like `Comp = ChildOne;` or `Comp = ChildTwo`.. then just do `<Comp />`

From [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) :

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, **assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.**

```js
class ChildOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Child One </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Child Two</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let condition = true; //Just for testing purpose

    let Comp = null;
    if (condition) Comp = ChildOne;
    else Comp = ChildTwo;

    return (
      <main>
        <Comp />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Container />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So easy!! i feel like a dumb. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to render components with the proper syntax: `<Comp>` instead of `{comp}`

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/01L8amgs/2/

Notice the Container class render function changed for this

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
      let condition = false;

      let Comp = null;      <===== Uppercased variable name
      if (condition) 
        Comp = ChildOne; 
      else
        Comp = ChildTwo; 

      return (
        <nain>
          <Comp />          <===== Render as component    
        </nain>
      )
  }
}
```